# Going Back to Make Correction on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

I am busy with input box selection and when I do an error I want to go back and make a correction but my code only allows me to make one selection and does not allow me to go back and make corrections, for example if I select "Yes", then realise I want to select "No" for the first option and I am already on the second option, I want be able to go back to my first input box and select "No". here is my code

```
ans = InputBox("1 = Yes" & vbCrLf & "2 = No", "Motor Davit")

Select Case ans
    Case "1":
        : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("Motor_Davit_" & Size)
        layerObj.LayerOn = True

    Case "2":
        : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("Motor_Davit_" & Size)
        layerObj.LayerOn = False
End Select

ans = InputBox("1 = Yes" & vbCrLf & "2 = No", "Two Pass")

Select Case ans
    'Select whether it's a Two Pass unit or wha
     Case "1":
         : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("TWO_PASS_" & Size)
         layerObj.LayerOn = True
     Case "2":
         : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("TWO_PASS_" & Size)
         layerObj.LayerOn = False                
     Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.", vbCritical, MSG: Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: I would say the only way is pressing cancel at the second input box to trigger the `Case Else` and then jump to the beginning (eg with a goto). Or tell the user not to hit OK until he is sure that his selection was correct. This is a user problem not a programming issue. Also check your syntax! There should be no `:` in front of `: Set`!

Comment: @Peh or after `Case "#"` for that matter

Comment: Might be better to use a form with both questions, a tick box and a single commit button.  The tick box will return TRUE/FALSE and you can feed that response directly to the `layerobj`.

Comment: I used a GoTo function to solve this, I had to give all the options a Label. Thanks guys!